# How do I add a debug option to Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I've got the below simple Makefile which I use for compiling a C program:

```
all:
    gcc -Wall -o myfile myfile.c lol_dht22/dht22.c lol_dht22/locking.c -lwiringPi -lcurl -lm
```

I want to add in a debug option so I can compile with -DDEBUG, so if I run

```
make
```

it compiles as normal. and if I run

```
make debug
```

it compliles with the debug flag.

I have read through a few tutorial but seems to be getting more and more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example makefile that has the two options you are looking for.

```
all:
    gcc -Wall -o myfile myfile.c lol_dht22/dht22.c lol_dht22/locking.c -lwiringPi -lcurl -lm
debug:
    gcc -DDEBUG -Wall -o myfile myfile.c lol_dht22/dht22.c lol_dht22/locking.c -lwiringPi -lcurl -lm
```

You just needed to add a debug option, which is done in similar fashion to the 'all' option you had already declared.

Comment: Just for the record this is very much not an idiomatic, or well-written, makefile.

Comment: @Etan Reisner you put it nicely Etan

Comment: The way I would put it is, it is not a makefile.  It is a shell script, that looks like a makefile.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to do it well, here it is.  You don't do `make debug`, instead, you should call

```
>make
```

or

```
>make DEFS=DEBUG
```

or

```
>make DEFS='ANY DEFINES YOU WANT'
```

In addition to normal Make rebuild criteria, the following Makefile recognizes rebuilds based on `DEFS`.

```
define DEPENDABLE_VAR

.PHONY: phony
$1: phony
    @if [[ `cat $1 2>&1` != '$($1)' ]]; then \
        echo -n $($1) > $1 ; \
    fi

endef

$(eval $(call DEPENDABLE_VAR,DEFS))


.PHONY: all
all: myfile

SRCS := myfile.c lol_dht22/dht22.c lol_dht22/locking.c
myfile: $(SRCS) Makefile DEFS
    gcc $(addprefix -D, $(DEFS)) -Wall -o $@ $(SRCS) -lwiringPi -lcurl -lm
```