# Makefile that rebuilds all if compiled with dif flags

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I am having a little bit of a tough time trying to figure out how to make my Makefile so that when I do `make` and it compiles a release version then later on do a `make debug` it compiles a debug version with the new `-DDEBUG` and `-g` set on gcc if the files have not been updated.

For example:

1. main.cpp is edited
2. run `make`
3. compiles main.cpp
4. run `make debug`
5. main.cpp is not recompiled because there were no changes even though the flags for compilation differ

Note I don't want to have to do a clean each time either because I dont want to have to recompile files if I do 2 `make`s in a row so setting clean as a dependency is not going to be a valid answer here

Comment: There are examples of this around, some possibly even on this site, but the general idea is that you write the compiler flags to a file, list that file as a prerequisite of your compiled objects, list a forced prerequisite for that file on a temporary file that you compare the current flags against and update the modification time (and contents) of your initial prereq file when the current flags differ from the old flags.

Comment: My answer follows the general idea that Etan is talking about.  The particular feature of my answer (mentioned in the different thread), is that it hides the complexities of the implementation of this hack, from the Makefile user - typically the person who updates a particular "package" Makefile.  They just want the simple interface, like I specified, they just want to "depend" on some variable in the same flexible ways as they can depend on files, and don't want to know how it happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to compile object files into a different directory depending on the build mode, e.g.:

```
# default mode, override with `make BUILD=release`
BUILD := debug
obj_dir := ${BUILD}

CFLAGS.debug := -g -O0
CFLAGS.release := -g -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG

all : ${obj_dir}/test

# Example executable
${obj_dir}/test : ${obj_dir}/test.o

test.c :
    echo "int main() { return 0; }" > $@

# Generic rules

${obj_dir} :
    mkdir $@

${obj_dir}/%.o : %.c Makefile | ${obj_dir} # Also recompile when Makefile changes.
    ${CC} -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${CFLAGS.${BUILD}} -MD -MP $<

${obj_dir}/% : Makefile | ${obj_dir} # Also re-link when Makefile changes.
    ${CC} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} $(filter-out Makefile,$^) ${LDLIBS}

clean :
    rm -rf ${obj_dir}

-include $(wildcard ${obj_dir}/*.d)

${obj_dir}/*.d : ;

.PHONY: all clean
```

(Bonus feature: automatic dependency generation).

Usage:

```
[max@localhost:~/tmp] $ make
mkdir debug
echo "int main() { return 0; }" > test.c
cc -c -o debug/test.o   -g -O0 -MD -MP test.c
cc -o debug/test  debug/test.o 

[max@localhost:~/tmp] $ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

[max@localhost:~/tmp] $ make BUILD=release
mkdir release
cc -c -o release/test.o   -g -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG -MD -MP test.c
cc -o release/test  release/test.o 

[max@localhost:~/tmp] $ make BUILD=release
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not run `make debug` - that would mean, you want to build a different target (`debug`).  But you don't, you want to build the *same* target, just with different options.  That's what you do, you run a different option, a variable value

```
>make DEBUG=Y
```

When you run

```
>make
```

you also pass that variable really, just with the empty string as value.

Now, in order for this to work as you want in the Makefile, you would want to make it as if `DEBUG` was a prerequisite file, with recipes like this:

```
foobar.o: foobar.c DEBUG
    gcc $(if $(DEBUG), -DDEBUG -g) -c $< -o $@
```

Of course, normally this won't work, because `DEBUG` is a variable, not a file.  So you need a hack, that I call "dependable variables".  It is basically a way to declare a variable to behave like a file.  I describe this technique in one of my other answers:

[How do I add a debug option to Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797287/how-do-i-add-a-debug-option-to-makefile/25801355#25801355)

Answer (score 0):

I once did something like this, it looked like that (boiled down to the minimum):

```
EXE     := a.out
SRC     := $(wildcard *.c)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug)
OBJ     := $(SRC:.c=.o)
else
OBJ     := $(SRC:.c=-d.o)
endif

.PHONY: all debug

all:    $(EXE)

debug:  CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug:  $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o %-d.o:  %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

The trick is to use two separate list of object files, and select one depending of the target.