# Makefile not always rebuilds

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile which takes a variable from the commandline and passes it to compiler (for C++ preprocesor).

Here is the code:

```
bar=0
file.o: foo.cpp    
ifeq($(bar), 0)
    g++ file.cpp -D foo=1 -o file.o
else
    g++ file.cpp -D foo=0 -o file.o
endif
```

The problem is that after running

```
make bar=0
```

and then

```
make bar=1
```

It says that foo.o is up to date (which it is, but I would want it rebuilt since a variable is changed inside the code).

Comment: Is it `foo.o` and `foo.cpp`, or `file.o` and `file.cpp`? And if you want an object file, you should add the `-c` flag when compiling.

Comment: You nead a `clean` target. Then `make clean`.

Comment: No he does not.  `make clean` is pointless. If you need to clean, why use Make.  Just write a shell script.  The whole point of Make is that one should not clean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in using `Make` at all if one resorts to forced rebuilds or cleaning.  The correct approach here is to implement a "dependable variable", that behaves like a file.  If `bar` were such a variable, you could just say

```
file.o: foo.cpp bar
    (your recipe here)
```

and that would mean, if the "contents" (value) of `bar` change, you rebuild.

For details on how to implement dependable variables, see my post

[How do I add a debug option to Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797287/how-do-i-add-a-debug-option-to-makefile/25801355#25801355)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) target for forcing compiler to rebuild it.
The good idea is to define clean function. Then to recompile project using:

```
make clean
make all
```

Comment: But then if I run 
    make bar=1
twice it will rebuild it without need, is there a way around this?

Comment: You may store bar value in temporary file and compare it prior every compilation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple and don't mind having an extra file as a marker, you could do

```
bar = 0
MARKER = compiled_with_foo_
file.o: $(MARKER)_$(bar)    
ifeq($(bar), 0)
    rm -f $(MARKER)_1
else
    rm -f $(MARKER)_0   
endif
    g++ -c file.cpp -D foo=$(bar) -o file.o

$(MARKER)_$(bar): file.cpp
    touch $@
```

and have your `clean` remove both markers.