# Makefile arguments to C definitions - requires clean

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile that I use to build an embedded project in C. When I build the project I pass an argument like the following so that a #define is set.

```
 make UID=ID123
```

In the makefile I have

```
ifdef UID
CFLAGS+=-DUID=\"$(UID)\" 
endif
```

And in the source code e.g. app.h I have

```
#ifndef UID
#define UID NOUID
#endif
```

The problem I am facing is that this works only if I clean the project first. Since the project is quite big, this takes a lot of time between recompilations.

How can this be avoided? Can the make program selectively build the files that are affected? Like when a file gets edited? Does removing the object files that this #define affects help or is a bad idea?

The reason this is necessary is so that programming 100 devices, each will have a unique ID passed to the program at build time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do, but some of there are pretty involved. It's a question of what your priorities are, and how much arcane Make-craft you want to do.

First you can figure out which object files depend on UID. Having such a list will save you a lot of work; for instance, you can remove only those object files and then rebuild them, instead of removing and rebuilding *all* object files with `clean`:

```
clean_uid_objects:
    rm -f $(UID_OBJECTS)
```

You can maintain this list yourself:

```
OBJECTS := foo.o bar.o
UID_OBJECTS := baz.o qux.o
```

or with some cleverness you *might* have Make construct the list on the fly, but explaining that one would take a while.

You can also have Make keep track of which UID you used, the last time you rebuilt the object files. After all, if you haven't changed it, then you don't have to rebuild anything because of it. One way to do that is to record the last UID in a file called, say, `UID_SAVE`. Then you can `include` that file in the makefile, and Make will adjust it (and rebuild the makefile, and rerun itself) when you pass it a new UID:

```
-include UID_save

ifdef UID
#CFLAGS+=-DUID=\"$(UID)\"
ifneq ($(UID),$(OLDID))
.PHONY: UID_SAVE
endif
endif

UID_save:
    @echo OLDID:=$(UID) > $@
```

Once you have *that* working, you can make `UID_SAVE` a prerequisite of the object files that depend on UID, so that no cleaning is necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you could point me to the right direction for the longer, third method you mentioned. For now I guess I'll remove some of the objects by maintaining a manual list.

Comment: @opcode: Which one, the one where Make figures out which files depend on UID, or the last code section from `-include ...` to the `UID_save` rule?

Comment: Oh sorry, the one where make figures it out. Where you said "...construct the list on the fly, but explaining that one would take a while." was that meant for the last solution or is it actually another solution?

Comment: @opcode: that's another part of the solution (it does no good on it's own but saves you the trouble of maintaining the list). A *general* way to do this is difficult, but constrained cases are easier. Does that `#ifndef UID` line appear in every source or header file that depends *directly* on UID? (Don't worry about source files that `#include` those header files for now.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
.PHONY: myfile1.c myfile2.c myfile1.h
```

to force rebuild the files that depend on the argument passed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Beta's last answer, but it shows the precise systematic method.  What you want, is have `UID` behave as if it were a file, not a variable, so you could depend targets on it.  Here is how to do it, see my answer in this post:

[How do I add a debug option to Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797287/how-do-i-add-a-debug-option-to-makefile/25801355#25801355)

You write the function `DEPENDABLE_VAR`.  Then, if you want a variable `UID` to be "dependable", you simply call that function:

```
$(eval $(call DEPENDABLE_VAR,UID))
```

and now you can write things like:

```
foobar.o: UID
```